# Why don't planes fly directly to their destination?

Tags: flight-path

Here is the flight path for [B62554](https://www.planemapper.com/flights/B62554) from PBI (Palm beach) to JFK. This flight almost *goes back on itself* when off the coast of South Carolina.
I was wondering why this flight takes such a contorted path? Another example is [B6242](https://www.planemapper.com/flights/B6242) from Havana to JFK, which similarly diverts out to see when near New Jersey then comes back at an almost 90 degree angle.

[image: flight path for B62554 from PBI to JFK, source planemapper.com]

Comment: Hi. See: [Why might an airliner fly a large U-turn before landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44641/14897) and [Why do some flights make turns shortly after takeoff?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29481/14897) and [Why do pilots use airways instead of just “flying direct” every time?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11506/14897) and [Why might this trans-pacific flight not follow a more direct route?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37748/14897) and [Why would an airliner make a 90° course change?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73314/14897)

Comment: Note that flights do not always follow the same route.  For example, FlightAware has [the last two weeks of flight paths for JetBlue 2554](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU2554) (scroll down to the table listing "Past Flights" to find them.)  The [flight on 2020-03-21](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU2554/history/20200321/1956Z/KPBI/KJFK), which you've included in your question, has several jogs & diversions.  The [flight on 2020-03-20](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU2554/history/20200320/1956Z/KPBI/KJFK) was much straighter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many reasons why planes don't fly direct to their destination.

- Mountains (for smaller piston aircraft)
- Traffic capacity and traffic flow considerations for the ATC center
- Weather along the route
- Preferred airway routings

For an analogy, cars don't drive direct to their destination for the same reasons.  Roads, I would venture to guess, would be preferred routings to your destinaiton.

There would be a traffic jam if everyone wanted to get to the closest airport for the Olympics at the exact same time.  Traffic flow considerations would dictate planes slow down or fly a different routing or wait till there is a time slot for them to land at their destination.